# Select images from gallery Python Kivy for Android

Tags: python, android, image, kivy

Can I load images from the gallery when I click a button by Python Kivy? I am a beginner, and I can not find an example on the Internet.

I want to make a simple application in which you need to select a picture from the phone and display it on the screen.

For example, to open a menu like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8yVQ.png)

I found an example of a filechooser for all directories on the device but it does not work on android (when I try to open some directory the application terminates)

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image

import os

class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    lbl_path = ObjectProperty(None)
    img = ObjectProperty(None)
    picture_path = ""

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as img:
            self.img.source = ''.join(filename)
            self.picture_path = self.img.source
            self.lbl_path.text = self.picture_path

        self.dismiss_popup()


class Editor(App):
    pass


Factory.register('Root', cls=Root)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

kivy (editor.kv):

```
Root:
img: img
lbl_path: lbl_path

canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        Button:
            text: 'Load'
            on_release: root.show_load()

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 20

        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            Image:
                id: img
                size_hint: (.8, .8) 

            GridLayout:
                rows: 3
                Label:
                    id: lbl_path
                    color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                    text: "Picture:"
                    size_hint: (.8, .8)  

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

        Button:
            text: "Load"
            on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Comment: please show us some of your code to start off

Comment: use intents using jnius

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the android phone storage data (images, videos,..) you need to grant permission for this
and you can do this in two steps

1. add the your permissions to `android.permissions` in your spec file like this :

   `android.permissions = READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
2. ask for the permission from the user from your code like this on build method like this :

```py
def build(self):
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

and then you can use kivy filechooser or kivymd filemanager to pick up and assets from phone storage